# What are the credentials heroku login is looking for?

Tags: django, git, heroku, web-deployment, django-deployment

When you're trying to deploy an app to Heroku, and you're prompted for the username and password for https://git.heroku.com and https://@git.heroku.com, are the credentials for these items the same as your credentials for your heroku account? Or are they your GitHub credentials? I've tried numerous combinations of both of my accounts, and I keep getting the error:

remote!: WARNING:
remote!: Do not authenticate with username and password using git
remote!: Run 'heroku login' to update your credentials, then retry the git commmand

I've rerun heroku login several times, entering the correct password to heroku each time, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use your heroku credential only.

When you successfully authenticated ~/.netrc have some information about the login.

For more `info`